# How can I establish a trigger to a script (python, ideally) in Git

Tags: python, git

How can I establish a trigger to a script (python, ideally) in Git that triggers when the main has any successful commits for a particular repo?  I need to establish an "auto push" mechanism to update particular remote filesystems.

If its possible to extend this to trigger on commits to a particular branch, that would be great.

Comment: Look at git hooks. You can write those in python.

Comment: Thanks!   exploring this and it looks like it will do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use case for **git hooks**.

You can start with [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and the web is full with information for you.

Comment: thanks, a little more research would have found this.   It does look suitable.

Comment: so it was useful for you? If so, it deserve a click on the up arrow ;-)

Comment: ooops, I upclicked, but don't have enough reputation to have it show publicly.   strange but true.